# Emacs ace jump mode: how to scroll?

Tags: emacs

As far as I can tell, ace jump will only jump to items found in the visible part of the buffer.  Once I activate ace jump, and matches to my selection are highlighted, I can jump to any of them, as long as they are visible.  But what do I do if I want to find matches in the part of the buffer that it not visible?  Attempts to scroll the buffer causes ace jump to quit.

Comment: That is by design and is unlikely to change. Use `isearch-forward` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want seems like a good idea, but it doesn't really work. You would need to know what keypress you need to get to an off-screen match, and you can't know what those are because they are off-screen. Ace-jump is for jumping around the visible buffer.

Other options are isearch, M-x occur or structured tools like imenu, speedbar, ecb and so on.

Comment: I would have thought that I would have been able to scroll down and see the hidden matches, and then press the appropriate key.  Thanks for the other ideas; I was not aware of them.

Comment: I can see your point, but then the answer would be to scroll down first! ace-jump is about getting the point in exactly the right place. Having said that it would be great to have ace-jump connect into something like occur, so if you don't get the match you want, you could drop into occur. Doesn't do it at the moment though.

Comment: I don't know that I have to scroll until I execute ace jump and don't see the instance I want.  Well it's not going to change, so we shouldn't be discussing the issue. But *occur* looks like it can work.

Comment: I just stumbled across helm-swoop.   This does what I want, but requires moving (C-n) through a list of matches until you get to the one you want.  More keystrokes, but it seems to work well.  It requires helm, and I'm not sure about that package yet ... it's really large.